# Was HindII the first restriction endonuclease to be extracted?

Tags: terminology, biotechnology

**Background:**

Guided by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_enzyme#Nomenclature) and [pmc](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4081073/#SEC2title) I found [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022283673901526) paper by Hamilton O. Smith. and .Daniel Nathans.

> A 
>   restriction 
>   enzyme 
>   is 
>   a 
>   component 
>   of 
>   a 
>   restriction-modification 
>   system 
>   of 
>   a 
>   given 
>   specificity 
>   within 
>   an 
>   organism. 
>   The 
>   R-MT 
>   system 
>   consists 
>   of 
>   two 
>   enzymatic 
>   components, 
>   a 
>   restriction 
>   endonuclease, 
>   and 
>   a 
>   modification 
>   enzyme 
>   sharing 
>   similar 
>   (or 
>   identical) 
>   recognition 
>   specificity. 
>   We 
>   would 
>   like 
>   to 
>   propose 
>   that 
>   the 
>   genus-species 
>   designation 
>   be 
>   used 
>   as 
>   an 
>   R-M 
>   system 
>   name 
>   according 
>   to 
>   the 
>   following 
>   rules.
>
> (1) 
>   The 
>   genus 
>   and 
>   species 
>   name 
>   of 
>   the 
>   host 
>   organism 
>   is 
>   identified 
>   by 
>   the 
>   first 
>   letter 
>   of 
>   the 
>   genus 
>   and 
>   the 
>   first 
>   two 
>   letters 
>   of 
>   the 
>   species 
>   to 
>   form 
>   a 
>   three-letter 
>   abbre- 
>   viation 
>   in 
>   italics. 
>   For 
>   example: 
>   E. 
>   coli, 
>   Eco 
>   and 
>   H. 
>   influenzae, 
>   Hin.
>
> (2) 
>   Strain 
>   or 
>   type 
>   identification 
>   follows 
>   the 
>   genus-species 
>   abbreviation 
>   in 
>   non- 
>   italicized 
>   symbols, 
>   e.g. 
>   EcoB 
>   or 
>   EcoK. 
>   In 
>   cases 
>   where 
>   the 
>   R-M 
>   system 
>   is 
>   genetically 
>   specified 
>   by 
>   a 
>   virus 
>   or 
>   pla,smid 
>   the 
>   italicized 
>   genus-species 
>   abbreviation 
>   of 
>   the 
>   host 
>   is 
>   given 
>   and 
>   the 
>   symbol 
>   for 
>   the 
>   extrachromosomal 
>   element 
>   follows 
>   in 
>   non-italics, 
>   e.g. 
>   EcoPl, 
>   EwRI, 
>   etc. 
>   In 
>   occasional 
>   cases 
>   where 
>   it 
>   might 
>   be 
>   necessary 
>   to 
>   specify the 
>   host 
>   strain 
>   as 
>   well 
>   as 
>   the 
>   extrachromosomal 
>   element 
>   the 
>   strain 
>   identification 
>   symbol 
>   may 
>   be 
>   inserted 
>   parenthetically, 
>   e.g. 
>   Eco(B)Pl.
>
> (3) 
>   When 
>   a 
>   particular 
>   host 
>   strain 
>   has 
>   several 
>   different 
>   R-M 
>   systems, 
>   these 
>   are 
>   identified 
>   by 
>   Roman 
>   numerals, 
>   thus, 
>   the 
>   R-M 
>   systems 
>   from 
>   H. 
>   injluenzae 
>   strain 
>   d 
>   would 
>   be 
>   HindI, 
>   HindII, 
>   HindIII, 
>   etc.

**Main question:**

Now *Hin*dII was -

1. extracted from  ***H***aemophilus **in**fluenzae
2. the strain was strain [Rd](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P44413), so **d**
3. and it was the **2nd** enzyme to be isolated? Hence II.

So how is it the first Type II RE?

> H.O. Smith, K.W. Wilcox, and T.J. Kelley, working at Johns Hopkins University in 1968, isolated and characterized the **first** restriction nuclease whose functioning depended on a specific DNA nucleotide sequence. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HindII))

Comment: I don't know how widely this has been accepted but Roberts proposed in 2003 that the italics should be dropped (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC152790/). I used to be a stickler for using italics, but I now prefer without.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about biology it's about history, and not very interesting history either. Why should you care whether it was HindIII or EcoRI for goodness sake!

Comment: I don't understand what can be wrong in getting a doubt cleared? The question (in the title which still stands unedited) was the main question behind this post. NCERT (a book back from my school) did not mention the Type II part to keep things simple. It lingered in my mind (as why an enzyme which is II yet the first) and definitely it was my silly mistake to not have observed the Type II thing even while reading it after so many years. My question wasn't which one's the 1st enzyme? But why Hind**II** the first one?  @David

Comment: I call them as I see them. (Friendly tip: best to try to avoid Indian English "doubt" on International forums — use "question" instead.)

Comment: if the strain is Rd then instead of Hind,HinR should have been written, what is the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The explanation here is quite simple: *Hin*dI, despite having been isolated/discovered before *Hin*dII, is a **type I** Restriction Enzyme, not a type II:

> A type I restriction enzyme from *Haemophilus influenzae*, Hind I, which requires adenosine 5'-triphosphate and 5-adenosyl methionine, was studied for its activity on transfecting and transforming deoxyribonucleic acid (DNA) [...] Most of the restriction enzymes from *Haemophilus* belong to type II restriction enzymes according to the classification system proposed by Boyer. These enzymes require only Mg2+ for their action in contrast to type I enzymes that require Mg2+, adenosine 5'-triphosphate (ATP), and S-adenosyl methionine (SAM).

(Source: [Biological Properties of a Haemophilus influenzae Restriction
Enzyme, Hind I](http://jb.asm.org/content/127/2/848.full.pdf))

Thus, in fact, *Hin*dII was the first **type II** Restriction Enzyme isolated/discovered, as it's well documented.

---

PS: As a bonus, here is a table with the main differences among RE types I, II, III and IV (Source: [Thermo Fisher Scientific](https://www.thermofisher.com/au/en/home/life-science/cloning/cloning-learning-center/invitrogen-school-of-molecular-biology/molecular-cloning/restriction-enzymes/restriction-enzyme-basics.html)):

**Type I:**

- Multi-subunit protein with both restriction and methylation activities
- ATP requirement
- Cleavage site a variable distance from recognition site

**Type II:**

- Specific recognition sequence
- Cleavage site within or close to recognition sequence
- Generates 5′ phosphate and 3′ hydroxyl termini at cleavage site
- Mg<sup>2+</sup> requirement for most

**Type III:**

- Two-part recognition sequence in inverse orientation
- Cleavage site a specific distance away from one of the recognition sequences
- ATP requirement

**Type IV:**

- Cleavage of only methylated DNA
- Cleavage site approximately 30 base pairs away from recognition site